# Get original value in save_post action hooka

Tags: php, hooks, actions

I'd like to get the original value of the `$post` on the `save_post` action. This way I can detect changes, and only do specific actions if the post content/title was changed.

Is this possible?

Comment: I think `save_post` hook is too late as the post is already saved. I currently don't have the time, but there should be hooks that fire earlier, check the source code of `wp_update_post()`

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution:

```
add_action('pre_post_update', function($post_id, $post_data) {
    global $original_post;

    $original_post = get_post($post_id);
}, 10, 2);

add_action( 'save_post_', function($post_id, $post, $update) {
    global $original_post;

    $original_post->post_title; // original post title
    $post->post_title; // new post title
}, 10, 3);
```